# Magento Forbidden Error

Tags: php, magento

I'm experiencing an error when trying to access the cart on my site built in Magento. I can't see why or how but it seems that it's trying to access index.php from the main site as per the error [here.](http://dev.wisefoodsupply.com/checkout/cart) Rather than /var/www/vhosts/wisefoodsupply.com/httpdocs/index.php, it should be /var/www/vhosts/wisefoodsupply.com/httpdocs/dev2/index.php

Is there somewhere that I have to define system paths?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It work fine if you add `index.php` into your URL

```
http://dev.wisefoodsupply.com/index.php/checkout/cart
```

I think your .htaccess does not work. If you are using shared hosting, you should check with your provider.

Answer (score 0):

Its URL Re-Write error, you have enabled from magento admin config...

Please try to open this url, its working fine...

http://dev.wisefoodsupply.com/index.php/checkout/cart